# How to get all remote logged on users with Logon Time

Tags: powershell, usersession, disconnected-session, logonserver

I wanted a simple way to get all (remote) logged on (and disconnected) users on all servers from my list.

I use the QUERY SESSION command for this purpose (as I found it to be the quickest and most reliable one). The command is called QWINSTA in my code (which is the same as QUERY SESSION) and works from Windows 2012 and up.

But with my script I will get the details of (server name, session name, session ID, and session state), but I need User IDOL time and User Logon time as well, but I feel with QWINSTA we cannot achieve that, with QUER User we can get those details.

Can someone help me to get all these details in my output (USERNAME, SESSIONNAME, ID, STATE, IDLE TIME, LOGIN TIME)

Below is my Code.

**Code**

```
## Clear Host Console
 Clear-Host
    
 ## Define Variable for Server Count
 $z = 0
    
 ##Set Default Script Location
 Set-Location -Path "C:\Users\reddy\Desktop\Active or Disc users"
        
 ## Provide List of Servers to Check for the Disconnected user session
 $Servers = Get-Content ".\Servers\AZ_Servers.txt"
    
 ## Get Servers Count
 $count = $Servers.count 
    
 ## Define Date for the Out file
 $dt = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
 $Date = Get-Date
    
 ## Define Path for the Out File
 $exportFile = ".\Out\RDP_DisConnected_Users.csv"
    
 ## Define Array for Storing the User sessions
 $openSessions = @()
    
 ## Loop through each server to find the User Disconnected session
 Foreach ($ServerName in $Servers)
 {
    
 #initiate counter for showing progress
     $z = $z + 1
    
 # Start writing progress 
 Write-Progress -Activity "Processing Server: $z out of $count servers." -Status " Progress" -PercentComplete ($z/$Servers.count*100)
    
 ## Add the servers if you want to exclude any
 $ExcludedServers = "EXCLUDESRV01", "EXCLUDESRV02", "EXCLUDESRV03"
 If ($ExcludedServers -notcontains $ServerName)
 {
 Write-Host "Getting session information for $ServerName"
 $sessions = qwinsta /server $ServerName| ?{ $_ -notmatch '^ SESSIONNAME' } | %{
 $item = "" | Select "ServerName", "Username", "Id", "State"
 $item.ServerName = $ServerName
 #$item.SessionName = $_.Substring(1,18).Trim()
 $item.Username = $_.Substring(19,20).Trim()
 $item.Id = $_.Substring(39,9).Trim()
 $item.State = $_.Substring(48,8).Trim()
 $item
 }
 $openSessions += $sessions | where { ($_.Username -ne "") -and ($_.Username -ne "Administrator") -and ($_.State -ne "Active")}
 }
 Else { Write-Host "Skipping named computer $ServerName" -ForegroundColor Green}
 }
    
 $openSessions | Export-Csv "$exportFile" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Wait, i'm a bit confused. If you know that `quser.exe` gets that information, why not just swap it for your `qwinsta.exe`?

Comment: I am trying that one but i am unable to find a way to do that for multiple servers for all the users

Comment: use it in your loop: `quser /server:$serverName`; just replace your `qwinsta`.

Comment: when i try that i am getting the error as - quser : No User exists for *

Comment: that means no user is logged in.

Comment: i am checking for 588 servers and it is giving the same output for all the servers, how I can achieve the LogOn time and IDOL time by just changing the qwinsta to query, we need to add the parameters related to those right.?

Comment: so you're manually running the code of `quser /server:computername` against those servers and it gives you that output?

Comment: not manually, from the script it self I am running for all those servers, even if i run with that quser how will I get the IDOL time and Logon time for each user

Answer (score 0):

I would just use

```
quser | Out-GridView
```

Then you get it in a grid.

As an alternative you can export it to CSV:

```
$active = quser
$active | Export-Csv -Path .\Users.csv
```

I hope I understood right, what you wanted...

Comment: but this will only check for my user in all the list of servers, but I want the script to check for all the users who are logged in

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to split the `quser` output into an object with properties:

```
# skip header line of output
quser | Select -Skip 1 | Foreach-Object {
    # create object with empty properties
    $obj = "" | Select Username,Sessionname,ID,State,IdleTime,LogonTime
    # split the line with each group of 2 or more spaces
    $tokens = $_ -split '\s{2,}'
    # Sessionname is only available if six tokens are present
    if ($tokens.count -eq 6) {
        $obj.sessionName = $tokens[1]
    }
    # triming leading space and > for the your session
    $obj.username = $tokens[0].TrimStart(' ','>')
    # assigning remaining properties
    $obj.id,$obj.state,$obj.idletime,$obj.logontime = $tokens[-4..-1]
    # output the object
    $obj
}
```

Comment: I tried the above script but the output is empty

Comment: I just tested this on a windows 10 system, windows server 2019 system, and a `/server` target of Windows server 2012 R2 from a 2019 system. All worked.

Comment: can you help me like where exactly i can use the above code in my script to get output from multiple servers

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach you can take:

```
## Provide List of Servers to Check for the Disconnected user session
$ExcludedServers = "EXCLUDESRV01", "EXCLUDESRV02", "EXCLUDESRV03" 
$servers = Get-Content ".\Servers\AZ_Servers.txt" | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_ -notin $ExcludedServers }
$serversCount = $servers.Count

## Define Path for the Out File
$exportFile = ".\Out\RDP_DisConnected_Users.csv"

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $serversCount; $i++)
{
    $server = $servers[$i]
    $h = $i + 1
    $progressSplat = @{
        Activity = "Attempting to query $h out of $serverCount"
        Status   = "Currently on $server."
        PercentComplete = [int]($h / $serverCount * 100)
    }
    Write-Progress @progressSplat
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        quser /server:$server 2>&1 | 
            ForEach-Object -Process `
            {
                if (-not($_ -match "Error")) {
                    ($_ -replace '\s{2,}', ',').Trim()
                }
            } | ConvertFrom-Csv | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ComputerName" -NotePropertyValue $server -PassThru |
                Export-Csv -Path $exportFile -Append -Force -NoTypeInformation
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning -Message "Unable to ping: [$server]"
    }
}
```

...it's the same logic you're using, just using `Quser.exe` instead. I also see that you define a `$date` variable that is never used.

You can use some *RegEx* to replace the "white space" for comma's which we will be able to `ConvertFrom-Csv` ignoring all errors. If you're looking to see if there was any issues when running the code, just add an extra `else` block to the `if` statement in the call to `quser` loop.